# Scroll content vertically with jquery.animate and jquery.scrolltop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am working on this [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/CxbYf/1/) which scrolls an element to show the hidden content.

But I cannot make it right, for instance,

1. when I scroll the content to reach **numbers 7,8** and I want to scroll back one step previous only to reach **numbers 5,6** but it scrolls up to reach **numbers 1,2**.
2. after it reaches up to **numbers 1,2** mistakenly, it scrolls straight down to reach **numbers 8,9** when I click the `more` button again.

How can I fix it?

Here is the plugin code,

```
(function($){

   $.fn.extend({ 

        scroll_up_down: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                associateScroller:           '.less',
                scrollTarget:                '.items-thread',
                scrollAmount:                40,
                callback:                     function() {}
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;
            var scroll_amount =  o.scrollAmount;
            var associate_scroller = o.associateScroller


            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                // Set the varible.
                var object = $(this);
                var scroll_target = $(o.scrollTarget);

                scroll_target.animate({scrollTop:scroll_amount}, 500);

                scroll_amount += o.scrollAmount;


                return false;

            });

            var $cm_2 = $(associate_scroller).click(function(e){

                // Set the varible.
                var scroll_target = $(o.scrollTarget);

                scroll_target.animate({scrollTop:-scroll_amount}, 500);
                scroll_amount -= o.scrollAmount;


                return false;
            });



        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the variable `scroll_amount`. First of all, it always scrolls back to the top because you pass in negative! scroll amount. You don't want to do that. Second you should modify the scroll amount before the animation rather than after it.

http://jsfiddle.net/CxbYf/2/

```
scroll_amount = ...;
scroll_target.animate({scrollTop:scroll_amount}, 500);
```

Comment: thanks so much for the correction, mrtsherman. I just came another problem - how can I stop the `scroll_amount` from increasing when the scroller reaches the bottom of the content? thanks!

Comment: sorry, also how can I stop `scroll_amount` from decreasing when the scroller is at or reaches the top of the content? thanks.

Comment: You will need to check the `scroll_amount` value before incrementing or decrementing. `scrollTarget[0].scrollHeight` will get you the upper bound and `0` for lower bound. This has a small bug, but should be enough for you to solve your problem now. http://jsfiddle.net/CxbYf/4/